# JavaFX - toggle button with separator

Tags: javafx-2

The Java FX Scen Builder contains quite a special form of a toggle button. Several Buttons are visually concatenated and separated by a small vertical line:

[image]

I wonder how this is done. Does somebody have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an [HBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html) of [ToggleButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/toggle-button.htm)'s all with the same [ToggleGroup](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ToggleGroup.html) and custom css.

There is an [example with source code](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2.2/samples/Ensemble/index.html#SAMPLES/Controls/Buttons/Pill%20Button) of displaying a similar control group in the [Ensemble](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html) sample application (which Ensemble terms a Pill Button).  The Ensemble sample source license is BSD I think, so you should be able to use it in your app.  Go to Ensemble, search for `Pill` in the Ensemble sample app, click on the "*Save NetBeans Project...*" button on the Pill Button sample and open the resultant project in NetBeans, full code, css and supporting image files will be included in the project.

Comment: @Daniel I think you'll find that all of it is accomplished with styles. My memory is that the fancy angle/arrow button in the Ensemble breadcrumb is achieved using CSS declared SVG paths.

Answer (score 2):

As an easier alternative to custom CSS, the [Controls FX project](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) provides the Segmented Button control, that allow to visually group buttons just like OP asked.

It is BSD licensed so I guess safe to use in most cases. And the library has many other useful and well designed controls.

The segmented button looks like this :

[image]

Very straightforward to use :

```
ToggleButton tb1 = new Button("Red");
ToggleButton tb1 = new Button("Green");
ToggleButton tb1 = new Button("Blue");

SegmentedButton seg = new SegmentedButton();
seg.getButtons().addAll(tb1,tb2,tb3);
hbox.getChildren().add(seg);
```

It allows to specify if the selection should be mutually exclusive or not. For the second bwhaviour (non mutually exclusive) set the segmented buttons's group to null :

```
seg.setToggleGroup(null);
```

Source :
http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/SegmentedButton.html

Comment: The only issue I found using this control was that you can unselect a selected toggle